# Using the same variable multiple times in a SQL query. Python code?

Tags: python, sql, variables

I am new to python. I have the following code where I need to call the same variable multiple times. How can I do this?

```
import psycopg2 as pg

conn = pg.connect("dbname='db' user='user' host='localhost'")    

q1 = """SELECT value FROM t1;"""
cur1 = conn.cursor()
cur1.execute(q1)

cur2 = conn.cursor()

for row in cur1:
     q2 = """SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE c1 = '%s' or c2 ='%s';""" 
     #what comes here? %s is the 'value' from q1  
     cur2.execute(q2)
     for row in cur2: 
        print(row)
```

How can I tell python to use 'value' for all appearances of '%s'? %(row) works when %s appears only once:

```
q2 = """SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE c1 = '%s' or c2 ='%s';"""(%row)
```

I searched the stackoverflow but could not find my answer. I hope it is not a duplicate question.
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`psycopg2` supports named parameters using `%(name)s` style parameter markers.
If you use the same named parameter multiple times in your query, the same parameter value wil be passed each time.

Here is an example from [the documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries):

```
cur.execute(
    """INSERT INTO some_table (an_int, a_date, another_date, a_string)
        VALUES (%(int)s, %(date)s, %(date)s, %(str)s);""",
    {'int': 10, 'str': "O'Reilly", 'date': datetime.date(2005, 11, 18)})
```

While this looks like string % formatting, it's actually not, so it's safe from SQL injection attacks, while string formatting (using either `%` or `.format()` is not.

Comment: In `psycopg3` I am getting this error `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string` when I use one the arguments twice.

Comment: Are you using %s format specifiers or %(varname) style? %s style needs one parameter passed per marker, but the other does not. Look at my answer for an example.

Comment: I am using %(varname)s marker but it is only working if I have one parameter per marker otherwise raising TypeError: not enough arguments for format string. I used your answer to develop my query.

Comment: I thonk it is because psycopg3 uses server-side parameter binding rather than client-side (see https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/from_pg2.html#server-side-binding for more info), so this technique may not work anymore.  I haven't used psycopg3, so I can't offer a workaround.